# Apply cumxxx (sum, min...) to a window of varying size in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum, rolling-computation

I would like to apply a `cumxxx` operation on a window of **varying size** in a DataFrame.
Considering following inputs:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import seed, randint
from collections import OrderedDict

p5h = pd.period_range(start='2020-02-01 00:00', end='2020-02-04 00:00', freq='5h', name='p5h')
p1h = pd.period_range(start='2020-02-01 00:00', end='2020-02-04 00:00', freq='1h', name='p1h')

seed(1)
values = [randint(0,10) for p in p1h]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values' : values}, index=p1h)

p5h_st_as_series = p5h.start_time.to_series()

df['OpeneningPeriod'] = df.apply(
              lambda x: p5h.to_series().loc[p5h_st_as_series.index <=
                                            x.name.start_time].index[-1],
                                 axis=1)
```

Result

```
df.head(20)
                  Values   OpeneningPeriod
p1h                                       
2020-02-01 00:00       2  2020-02-01 00:00
2020-02-01 01:00       9  2020-02-01 00:00
2020-02-01 02:00       1  2020-02-01 00:00
2020-02-01 03:00       4  2020-02-01 00:00
2020-02-01 04:00       1  2020-02-01 00:00
2020-02-01 05:00       7  2020-02-01 05:00
2020-02-01 06:00       7  2020-02-01 05:00
2020-02-01 07:00       7  2020-02-01 05:00
2020-02-01 08:00      10  2020-02-01 05:00
2020-02-01 09:00       6  2020-02-01 05:00
2020-02-01 10:00       3  2020-02-01 10:00
2020-02-01 11:00       1  2020-02-01 10:00
2020-02-01 12:00       7  2020-02-01 10:00
2020-02-01 13:00       0  2020-02-01 10:00
2020-02-01 14:00       6  2020-02-01 10:00
2020-02-01 15:00       6  2020-02-01 15:00
2020-02-01 16:00       9  2020-02-01 15:00
2020-02-01 17:00       0  2020-02-01 15:00
2020-02-01 18:00       7  2020-02-01 15:00
2020-02-01 19:00       4  2020-02-01 15:00
```

Here, the `cumxxx` is to be applied on the 5-hour period defined. It can be of varying length because windows can be a day period (some with DST), or a month period (not constant number of hours in a month).

Result I am looking for is:

```
df_result.head(11)
                  Values   OpeneningPeriod   Cumsum
p1h                                       
2020-02-01 00:00       2  2020-02-01 00:00        2  <- cumsum starts with a new period
2020-02-01 01:00       9  2020-02-01 00:00       11
2020-02-01 02:00       1  2020-02-01 00:00       12
2020-02-01 03:00       4  2020-02-01 00:00       16
2020-02-01 04:00       1  2020-02-01 00:00       17
2020-02-01 05:00       7  2020-02-01 05:00        7  <- cumsum starts with a new period
2020-02-01 06:00       7  2020-02-01 05:00       14
2020-02-01 07:00       7  2020-02-01 05:00       21
2020-02-01 08:00      10  2020-02-01 05:00       31
2020-02-01 09:00       6  2020-02-01 05:00       37
2020-02-01 10:00       3  2020-02-01 10:00        3  <- cumsum starts with a new period
```

It would be the same logic with `cummin` & `cummax`.
Does anyone has any idea?

Thanks for any help!
Bests,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need grouping by `5H` window by `DatetimeIndex` use [`DataFrame.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_period.html) with `cumsum`:

```
df['Cumsum'] = df.resample('5H')['Values'].cumsum()
```

Or [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df['Cumsum'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5H'))['Values'].cumsum()
```

---

```
print (df.head(11))
                  Values   OpeneningPeriod  Cumsum
p1h                                               
2020-02-01 00:00       2  2020-02-01 00:00       2
2020-02-01 01:00       9  2020-02-01 00:00      11
2020-02-01 02:00       1  2020-02-01 00:00      12
2020-02-01 03:00       4  2020-02-01 00:00      16
2020-02-01 04:00       1  2020-02-01 00:00      17
2020-02-01 05:00       7  2020-02-01 05:00       7
2020-02-01 06:00       7  2020-02-01 05:00      14
2020-02-01 07:00       7  2020-02-01 05:00      21
2020-02-01 08:00      10  2020-02-01 05:00      31
2020-02-01 09:00       6  2020-02-01 05:00      37
2020-02-01 10:00       3  2020-02-01 10:00       3
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael, I retain your 1st solution with resample. Do you know if with resample, it is also possible to retain the first value, but keeping the index as it is? (ie duplicating the 1st value to the 4 following rows) If I apply first(), the index is resampled with a '5H' frequency. So intermediate rows are not kept.

Comment: @pierre_j - I think you need `df['first'] = df.resample('5H')['Values'].transform('first')`

Answer (score 1):

`groupby` should be a good startpoint :

```
df['Cumsum'] = df.groupby('OpeneningPeriod')['Values'].cumsum()
```

It gives:

```
                  Values  OpeneningPeriod  Cumsum
p1h                                              
2020-02-01 00:00       2 2020-02-01 00:00       2
2020-02-01 01:00       9 2020-02-01 00:00      11
2020-02-01 02:00       1 2020-02-01 00:00      12
2020-02-01 03:00       4 2020-02-01 00:00      16
2020-02-01 04:00       1 2020-02-01 00:00      17
2020-02-01 05:00       7 2020-02-01 05:00       7
2020-02-01 06:00       7 2020-02-01 05:00      14
2020-02-01 07:00       7 2020-02-01 05:00      21
2020-02-01 08:00      10 2020-02-01 05:00      31
2020-02-01 09:00       6 2020-02-01 05:00      37
2020-02-01 10:00       3 2020-02-01 10:00       3
2020-02-01 11:00       1 2020-02-01 10:00       4
2020-02-01 12:00       7 2020-02-01 10:00      11
2020-02-01 13:00       0 2020-02-01 10:00      11
2020-02-01 14:00       6 2020-02-01 10:00      17
2020-02-01 15:00       6 2020-02-01 15:00       6
...
```